# 1031 Exchange - Single Family residential - duplex

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax

Is it possible to a use a 1031 exchange to go from a single family residential to duplex where one side is rented the other is lived in?

Comment: Your question seems to assume that you will be living in one side of the duplex.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the 1031 can only apply to the rental side of the duplex, so half the duplex would have to cost as much (or more) as the sold property else you'd only get partial benefit and still face some capital gains tax and depreciation recapture.